# IMPLICIT to EXPLICIT conversion SQL state 42601 postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I am doing a course on PostgresSQL.  I am running the below select as per the course video, and it is supposed to be about factorials (new to this):

```
select 20 !;
```

it returns this error on my machine but not on the instructors, as shown on his video.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 1: select 20 !;  
                   ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 12
```

Is there some sort of extension/plugin that needs to be installed?
I am working on *PostgreSQL 14* using *pgAdmin 4*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `!` operator was removed in Postgres 14

[Quote from the release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/release-14.html)

> Remove factorial operators `!` and `!!`, as well as function `numeric_fac()` (Mark Dilger)
> The `factorial()` function is still supported.